# C++ smart pointers e funções

Tags: c++, funções, parâmetros, smart-pointer

Estou lendo um artigo no msdn sobre smart pointers. No artigo existe esse exemplo:

```
class LargeObject
{
public:
    void DoSomething(){}
};

void ProcessLargeObject(const LargeObject& lo){}
void SmartPointerDemo()
{    
    // Create the object and pass it to a smart pointer
    std::unique_ptr<LargeObject> pLarge(new LargeObject());

    //Call a method on the object
    pLarge->DoSomething();

    // Pass a reference to a method.
    ProcessLargeObject(*pLarge);

} //pLarge is deleted automatically when function block goes out of scope.
```

Minha dúvida está na função `ProcessLargeObject`. Obrigatoriamente a passagem tem que ser por referência? E se a funçao `ProcessLargeObject` tivesse a seguinte assinatura `ProcessLargeObject(LargeObject *lo)` qual seria a diferença?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, do jeito que a funçao ProcessLargeObject() está declarada, o objeto é passado como uma referência imutável. Por ser imutável, não é menos seguro do que passar por valor, além de ser mais rápida para objetos de tamanho não-trivial.

Existe uma diferença importante entre referências e ponteiros: as referências **não podem ser nulas**. Neste caso, a função ProcessLargeObject() sempre quer receber um objeto válido. Se fosse necessário às vezes passar NULL (como é comum fazer quando o parâmetro é "opcional") aí seria necessário usar ponteiro como parâmetro.

Lingugens mais modernas têm abolido esse idioma "objeto ou nulo" em favor de garantir um objeto sempre válido no próprio tipo. Por exemplo, no Swift um Tipo? pode ser "Tipo ou nil" enquanto "Tipo" é obrigatoriamente um objeto Tipo. Para extrair o objeto de uma variável Tipo? é preciso escrever "variável!" para deixar claro o que está acontecendo.